# Munin: how to ignore reset of counter

Tags: munin

I have a munin graph to see how many requests my application is getting every minute.
In order to do that I specify "graph_period minute" and I set my counter to be of type DERIVE ("counter.type DERIVE"). The only issue is that when I restart my application the counter will go back to zero and munin will have a negative number for number of requests in the graph.

Is there any way to tell munin that the counter is monotonically increasing so that if the counter decreases then it doesn't graph a negative value and updates it's current value to the new value of the counter?

Answer (score 1):

Juste use :

```
counter.type COUNTER
```

In some cases you might prefer :

```
counter.type DERIVE
counter.min 0
```

[Source](http://munin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/architecture/syntax.html#datatypes)